# Is it possible to do a fixed header with a max-width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position

I have a centered header div at the top of the site; it is currently not fixed and has a max-width set so that it is capped and responsive. This is really easy to do; you just set the max-width and use the margin to center it.

My client now wants the header to be fixed to the top of the page when he scrolls down. How do I keep the centered max-width(capped and responsive) there and make it fixed?

Comment: You could set the position to fixed and top, left, and right to 0.  Set margins and padding to 0.  Also set the z-index high so it's always on top.

Comment: Wouldn't that be more like width:100%? I want max-width:900px so that the width is capped.

Comment: Then don't set left or right values.  Set max-width to 900 and left/right margins to auto.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick on top of your page your header using `position:fixed;` and `top:0;`

https://jsfiddle.net/yxuk5guh/2/

```
#header {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#content {
    height: 1800px;
}
```

Comment: I need the blue header to adhere to the left and right margin like the text. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: I want to make a clarification. I need the blue header to adhere to the left and right margins when the width of the browser is less than the max-width. See how the header goes into the left and right margin? When the width of the browser is greater than the max width it works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

The HTML

```
<div class='fixed-top'>
    <h1 align='center'>Example Fixed Top Header</h1>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.fixed-top {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;

    background-color: blue;
   }
.container{
    padding-top:200px;
 height: 1800px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grk6petn/

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed with top, left, right set to 0.  Then use margin left/right auto.  Add 100% width and apply a max-width.  Don't forget a large z-index.

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pa2xxxjn/1/

Comment: Very close, but I need the blue part to adhere to the body margin, because  I need the edge of the blue to line up with edge of the green at all times.

Comment: @Ryan does this solve your problem http://jsfiddle.net/pa2xxxjn/2/ ? Basically set navbar and content to have the same margin-top.

Comment: @GibboK Thank you for taking a look for me. No that's not it. I meant the left and right margin. I just need the blue to stay out of the left and right margin like the green.